# Two easy rebus puzzles

Tags: rebus

> **Here are two easy, phrase, rebus puzzles**

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1.

> Face the music

2.

> Limelight

Comment: That is correct :D

Answer (score 7):

1.

> Face the music

2.

> Lemon sunset (a particular shade of sunset)

Comment: Hmm second one not so convincing.

Comment: Why can't it be sunrise?

Comment: @VortexYT; who's ever heard of a lemon sunrise? :)

Comment: Not me, but due to my limited knowledge, sunset isn't something either.

Answer (score 7):

JonMark got the first one, but I feel that the second one needs improvement. I offer:

> [Sublime Sunset](http://www.bbc.com/travel/story/20130910-sublime-sunsets-around-the-world)
>
>  Sub- *prefix* [as in "under"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sub-#Prefix), like subtitle, subzero etc., because the sun is under the lime.

Comment: Could you please add in an explanation for the first 3 letters of the spoilered answer? I'm not seeing how you got that...